# What can heroes carry and how do I see their full inventory?

Tags: heroville

I've noticed that you can mouse-over a hero's damage and see what I assume to be their inventory.  However, I've only ever seen a single weapon, 1 portal, 1 instant repair, and a shield, despite having plenty of gold to buy more.

[image: fredley the Porkchop]

I also notice a lack of potions in this list.  Also, I watched one hero have their weapon break, which lead to the Instant Repair being removed and another of the same type being added, so I have a feeling the mouse-over tip is not the full inventory.

Is there a way to view the full inventory of a hero?  Are there maximums on how many of each item (weapon, potion, etc.) a hero can buy?  Can a hero carry different weapons at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroes can only have 1 of each accessory and 1 weapon in the current game.

Potions are not taken into dungeons, rather they are consumed on the spot to provide a bonus to healing a hero between dungeons while they are in town.

Comment: So how does the Instant Repair work, then?  Do they buy a second weapon as the first breaks?

Comment: The instant repair will replace a weapon that breaks when they are in the middle of a dungeon. It is unusual that a weapon would break twice in one dungeon and the instant repair is usually bought again.

Comment: So the Instant Repair just becomes the weapon they had?  They don't have to buy a new one?

Comment: That is correct, it used to be they purchase a new one but it caused some issues so that feature was disabled